# Sankalpam for Berlin (Germany)

Tags: sankalpa

Kindly Help me with SANKALPAM for BERLING ( GERMANY ). I NEED TO PERFORM ON LINE PUUJA TO MY RELATIVES. THEY RECENTLY WENT TO BERLIN AND THEY DONT KNOW SANKALPAM. PLEASE GIVE ME SOLUTION

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.